# How to configure Jetty application on Android to accept JSP?

Tags: java, android, jsp, jetty

When I deploy a war on jetty application on Androïd, I get this message :

```
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /index.jsp. 
Reason:
JSP support not configured
```

How to configure Jetty application on Androïd to accept JSP?

Answer (score 1):

Android does not have an onboard compiler, so standard JSP support is not possible.

However, if you pre-compile your JSPs then you *might* be able to get them working on Android.

Use the jspc compiler, compile JSPs into classes, ensure that the `WEB-INF/web.xml` entries exist for every JSP file (usually done by JSPC compiler / build tools).

Make sure your war file does not include the actual JSP files, and at that point there's no longer a JavaC compiler requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to compile JSP or Java source on Android. All java source must be compiled into DEX. There is A-Jetty (not I-Jetty) to precompile and run JSP on Android. JSP precompiled into JAR then converted into DEX (apk). Precompiled JSP by standard Tomcat or JSPC will not work on Android cause they used java.beans package that not exist on Android.